# VBA copies only first row to text file

Tags: excel, vba7, vba6

I am looking to copy non-blank column data into a text file, while the copy is successful, the paste part of the vba copies only first row to the text file. Below are the issues

1.Though copy of the entire column is successful, the copy also has some blank cells (but has formulae), excel copies those cells too. I would like to ignore cells having only formulae.
2.Paste part of the code pastes pastes only first row of the copied column

```
Sub Addtotext() 'Adds stocks to stockslist for python
Dim strPath As String
Dim strName As String
Dim FSO As Object
Dim oFile As Object
Dim c As Range

With Range("J2", Range("J" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Copy
End With

strName = "a.txt"
strPath = "C:\Volume\PythonProjects"

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")


Set oFile = FSO.CreateTextFile(strPath & strName)

For Each c In Selection
    oFile.Write c.Value & " "
Next c

oFile.Close
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code doesn't seem to do or even attempt to do all the things you are describing.

Comment: Aside ... also just find it funny that the vba6 and vba7 tag both say they have nothing to do with vba6 or vba7...

Comment: @topsail not a programming guy, went along with prompt. what would be relevant for this query to suggest VBA macros? Also, the copy part works as expected, i have checked by pasting manually.

Comment: Well, it's a relief to know AI is still this bad at writing code - although maybe if you explain what you want better it will give you a better answer. The obvious parts that need to be fixed is ignoring blank rows and formulas (and the obvious answer is to at least TRY to do something to ignore blank rows and formulas).

Comment: Instead of creating a textfile and adding to it, you could instead creating your sheet how you want it and afterwards save it as txt.